# count rows laravel 5.2 and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a count of rows by some Id, what I've got:

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Domains extends Model
{
  protected $connection ='dns';
  protected $table = 'domains';
  protected $fillable = [
      'id', 'name', 'master', 'last_check', 'type'
  ];
  public $timestamps = false;

  public function records(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Records');
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Models\Domains;

class DomainsController extends Controller
{
  public function index() {
    $domains = Domains::all();
    $records = records::where('domain_id', '=', $domain_id)->get();
    return $domains;
  }
  public function show($id) {
    $domain_id = $id;
    $records = Records::where('domain_id', '=', $domain_id)->get();
    //return $records;
    return View::make('domainView.show')->with('records', $records);
  }
}
```

But when I access to domains in front-end I cant get the records count;

Front-end controller:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
      .module('webServices')
      .controller('DomainController', DomainController);

      function DomainController($http) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.domains;
        vm.error;
        $http.get('api/domains').success(function(domains) {
          console.log(domains);
          vm.domains = domains;
        }).error(function(error) {
          vm.error = error;
        });
      }
})();
```

How can I get the count of rows from table records, is in the same db that domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the rows, I use:

Laravel controller:

```
  public function index() {
    $domains = Domain::all();
    $domains = Domain::with('records')->get();
    return $domains;
  }
```

Angular controller:

```
  vm.getDomains = function () {
   $http.get('api/domains').success(function(domains) {
     vm.domains = domains;
   }).error(function(error) {
     vm.error = error;
   });
  }
```

Angular view:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="domain in domain.domains">
      <tr>
          <td>{{domain.name}}</td>
          <td>{{domain.type}}</td>
          <td>{{domain.records.length}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Thanks @somu and @Schellingerht for your answers, helps me to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. Use `length`, that's not AngularJS, but native JavaScript:

```
console.log(vm.domains.length); // prints number of domains to console
```

Or

```
alert(vm.domains.length); // gives an alert with number of domains to console
```

Your AngularJS looks like:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

  angular
      .module('webServices')
      .controller('DomainController', DomainController);

      function DomainController($http) {
          var vm = this;
          vm.domains = [];
          vm.error = null;

          $http.get('api/domains').success(function(domains) {
              vm.domains = domains;
              console.log(vm.domains.length); // Prints length of domains in your console;
          }).error(function(error) {
              vm.error = error;
          });
      }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what i want is to count the records associated to a domain, not the domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following things in your laravel code.

```
$count = Domains::count()
```

to know the total number of rows in domains table.

U can also use

```
  $records = records::where('domain_id', '=', $domain_id)->get();
  count($records);
```

to know the total number of records fetched.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and how can I show that in angularjs?